# How do I correctly populate a JQuery datatable using array of objects?

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-plugins, datatables-1.10

The table is generated properly with the right number of rows and columns but the cells are empty. Source of data is an array of objects.

The code I used:

```
  $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    data:ar3,
    "columns": [
        { title: "balance" },
        { title: "employeedetails" },
        { title: "position" },
        { title: "salaryamt" },
        { title: "startingdate" }
    ]
} );
    `
```

Comment: try with data without quotes and in small like this data:ar3

Comment: thanks but still the same

Comment: It'd be nice if you could not add images BUT as code snippet right here in the question. Anyway, the data you're using is an object array so you gotta use the `data` option within the columns along with `title` - [example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data)

Comment: worked like magic thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!